# AngularJS - module uses config from a different file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-module, angularjs-config

I am new to AngularJS and I don't know if this is possible.

This is my current code:

```
var app = angular.module('qlikCockpitApp',['pascalprecht.translate','720kb.tooltips']);

app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
... 
});
```

I want to move this app.config to another file, and access from my module file. Is it possible? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can add 2 file or more for each part of your application
>
> Remember in this case you have **1 app** this mean **`(var app = angular.module('qlikCockpitApp', []))`**

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('qlikCockpitApp',['pascalprecht.translate','720kb.tooltips']);
```

**app.config.js**

```
app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
 ... 
});
```

add files in your **index.html** with right sort:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="app.config.js"></script>
```

**Using Labjs:** if you want to load files as lazyload

**index.html**

```
<div id="app"></div>
<!--required: download labjs library-->
<script src="lab-library.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrapper.js"></script>
```

> in this case do not use `ng-app` set `id` attribute

**bootstrapper.js**

```
$LAB.script(
    "/angular.js",
    "/app.js",
    "/app.config.js"
)
.wait(function () {
    var root = document.getElementById("app");
    angular.bootstrap(root, ["app"]);
});
```

> Add `/` before files directory

Comment: Better practice to get rid of global `app` variable and reference using `angular.module`. https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/a1#modules

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! is there a way to do this without inserting <script> tags in my html file??

Comment: Yes, you can use `$LAB` OR `Labjs` actually you need to Read & Develop before using it.

Comment: it worked and it's better than inserting <script> tags, but still, is there a way to insert ONLY my main js file? 

<script src="../app.js"></script>